# ggplot2, dlply: Plots over n pages

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I am trying to create multiple plots (based on a facet) to be printed into as many pdf pages as needed. These plots represent the number of citations authors get over the years of their single publications. 
Here a toy dataset:

```
Publications <-data.frame(Year=c(1,2,1,2,3,4,5),Publication=c(rep("A"),rep("B"),rep("C"),rep("D"),rep("E"),rep("F"),rep("G")),Author=c(rep("John",2),rep("Michael",5)),Citations=c(5,6,4,7,2,3,8))
```

To do so, I start creating a general plot and assigning it to "a" as follows:

```
a = ggplot(data = Publications, aes(x = Year, y = Citations, label=Citations)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

Finally, I split the sample by my facet variable "Author" and save it in a pdf as follows:

```
require(plyr)
plots <-dlply(Publications, .(Author), function(x) a %+% x + 
                facet_wrap_paginate(Author ~ Publication, ncol = 1, nrow = 3))
pdf()
plots
dev.off()
plots$plots
```

This code produces a pdf with two pages. In page 1, two plots are displayed that correspond to author "John". In page 2, three plots corresponding to author "Michael" are displayed as specified in the code as well. The PROBLEM is that author "Michael" actually has 5 publications. So, for this author 5 plots should have been displayed (3 in page 2 and the remaining 2 in another/next page). My questions are, how can I write the code such that it produces as many pdf pages as needed? At the moment it produces 1 page per facet/level variable "Author". However, if I allow this, for some Authors there will be too many plots in one page, making it difficult to read. So, there should be only 3 plots per page but as many pages as needed.

Answer (score 1):

according to ggforce's help page,

> "Usually this will be put in a loop to render all pages one by one"

so one is expected to compute the number of pages and proceed with a for loop.

An alternative would be marrangeGrob,

```
require(plyr)
plots <- dlply(Publications,
               .(Author, Publication), "%+%", e1 = a)
gridExtra::marrangeGrob(grobs = plots, nrow=3, ncol=1)
```